# Snowflake External Table Partition - Granular Path

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external-tables

Experts,

We have our JSON files stored in the below folder structure in S3 as
**/appname/lob/2020/07/24/12,/appname/lob/2020/07/24/13,/appname/lob/2020/07/24/14**

```
stage @SFSTG = /appname/lob/
```

We need to create a external table with partition based on the hours. We can derive the partition part from the metadata$filename. However question here is should the partition column should be created as timestamp or varchar?

Which partition datatype helps us in better performance when accessing the file from snowflake using External table.

Comment: DATE is better than varchar or timestamp here.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake's recommendation is the following:

```
date_part date as to_date(substr(metadata$filename, 14, 10), 'YYYY/MM/DD'),
```

*Double check 14 is the correct start of your partition in your stage url I may have it incorrect here.

Full example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE Database.Schema.ExternalTableName(
  date_part date as to_date(substr(metadata$filename, 14, 10), 'YYYY/MM/DD'),
  col1 varchar AS (value:col1::varchar)),
  col2 varchar AS (value:col2::varchar))
  PARTITION BY (date_part)
  INTEGRATION = 'YourIntegration'
  LOCATION=@SFSTG/appname/lob/
  AUTO_REFRESH = true
  FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = JSON);
```

Comment: recommend leveraging SPLIT_PART, rather than a substring, so you can parse to the correct sub-folder.  This helps when folder names vary in length.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info! I just took the example straight out of Snowflake's docs but I did question that part of the logic myself ha!

Comment: @CodeMonkey & @ Mike Walton - Thanks -  However we like to have @ Hour level, i believe snowflake to recommend to keep at the lowest grain. Do you see any issue having @ Hour level folder, instead of day level? - Thanks !!

Comment: This depends on how much data is in an hour.  If you have enough data to warrant splitting by hour, then this would be fine.  If your hourly files are very small, then I'd keep it to date.

Comment: @MikeWalton - Thanks for the response, Yes we have quite number of files. My question  here is when i take until Hour ,can i have partition column varchar? as mentioned in my questions.

Comment: Yes, you can either do VARCHAR or a datetime to the hour.  Either works.